# Why kotlin can using a different name to call a function?

Tags: kotlin

I'm a beginner in Kotlin, I'm referencing a project that happened to see this code but did not understand its rules.
Specifically, the first time, I thought `parentFragment` in line 78 was a variable but after that, I find out this is a function with name `getParentFragment`. I wonder why the IDE understands that `parentFragment` is `getParentFragment` function.

This is where the `parentFragment` is used (full code here: https://pastebin.com/t5Rb8mb8)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJxYb.jpg)
And This is where the `getParentFragment` function is defined (Fragment.java file of Android)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0PPE.jpg)

Sorry because my account is new, so I can't embed an image

Comment: Properties have getters and setters (if the property is writable) automatically. So while you declared a property (`parentFragement`) you got the getter `getParentFragment()` automatically. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer okay I got it, I have read it but I didn't realize it used in this case. Thank you so much.

Comment: The getter `getParentFragment` of the Java class is called as a property `parentFragment` in the Kotlin code. This is how Java code can be called from Kotlin. You can read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters). The Kotlin compiler understands that `parentFragment` is indeed `getParentFragment`